# Unity 2d Animation Controller, problem with idle animations

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

How can i add idle animations to this code? I'm trying to use GetButtonUp (the animation should be played when key is released) in if's for given keys and then in brackets Player.GetComponent().Play("goidle"); and like that in every if but i doesn't seems to work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Vertical")) //pressing w
        {
            Player.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("goup");
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("VerticalDown")) //pressing s
        {
            Player.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("godown");
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Horizontal")) //pressing d
        {
            Player.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("goright");
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("HorizontalDown")) //pressing a
        {
            Player.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("goleft");
        }     
}
```

Here is the code when i try to use GetButtonUp and start playing the idle animation for every direction

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Player;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Vertical"))
        {
            Player.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("goup");
        }

            if (Input.GetButtonUp("Vertical"))
            {
                Player.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("idleup");
            }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("VerticalDown"))
        {
            Player.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("godown");

            if (Input.GetButtonUp("VerticalDown"))
            {
                Player.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("idledown");
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Horizontal"))
        {
            Player.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("goright");

            if (Input.GetButtonUp("Horizontal"))
            {
                Player.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("idleright");
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("HorizontalDown"))
        {
            Player.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("goleft");

            if (Input.GetButtonUp("HorizontalDown"))
            {
                Player.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("idleleft");
            }
        }

       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply using an else condition after all your ifs ?

so like

if //do this
if //do that
if //do something else

else  Player.GetComponent().Play("goidle")

Also to make your code neater maybe add a getComponent at start for the Animator ?

```
public class AnimationController : MonoBehaviour

public GameObject Player;
Animator playerAnimator;

void Start()
{
    playerAnimator = Player.GetComponent<Animator>().
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Vertical"))
    {
        playerAnimator.Play("goup");
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("VerticalDown"))
    {
        playerAnimator.Play("godown");
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Horizontal"))
    {
        playerAnimator.Play("goright");
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("HorizontalDown"))
    {
        playerAnimator.Play("goleft");
    }

    else
    {
        playerAnimator.Play("goidle")
    }

}
```

---

Also why not use Triggers ?

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html